# How to remove and preview images with Cloudinary?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I have a problem with either Cloudinary or Attachinary. I can upload an image but I can't remove it or see the preview when selecting it, the only thing I can see is `select a file` button and I am not sure what is causing this. The API key is correct.

My app.js

```
//= require jquery-fileupload
//= require cloudinary/jquery.cloudinary
//= require attachinary
//= require tree
```

init-attachinary.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.attachinary-input').attachinary();
});
```

I think the problem comes from the `JS`.

Comment: any console error?

Comment: i have a console error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attachinary is not a function" @FabrizioBertoglio

Comment: did you follow the installation instructions? https://github.com/cloudinary/attachinary#installation did you install the gem with `gem 'attachinary'` and then running `bundle install`? did you restart the server? I believe you do not have `jquery.cloudinary.js` in your asset pipeline, that is where the function `.attachinary()` is defined https://github.com/cloudinary/attachinary/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/attachinary.js.coffee#L3 check please in your `chrome` developer tools `source` that you have that file `jquery.cloudinary` in your asset pipeline

Comment: Yes i follow the instructions and the gem attachinary is install i will check for the js file @FabrizioBertoglio

Comment: No i dont have jquery.cloudinary in my asset pipeline, i should reinstall cloudinary and attachinary ? @FabrizioBertoglio

Comment: The gem installation should include those files, but somehow this is not working. Maybe you can temporarily fix this by including that `js` file in your asset pipeline under `app/assets/javascripts`

Comment: I added this file in my assets but i still have the consol error @FabrizioBertoglio

Comment: do you have the file in your assets? maybe you should include in your `application.js` the following code `require jquery.cloudinary`